Next.js Prisma FindMany Query Fails for Certain Search Strings in PostgreSQL
My Question: How can I modify my query to include terms like "United States" without causing errors?
I am using Prisma with PostgreSQL and facing an issue with the findMany method. Here's the scenario:
The following query works fine:
const result = await prisma.posts.findMany({
  where: {
    body: {
      search: 'France | Argentina',
    },
  },
})

However, changing the search string to include "United States" results in a syntax error:
const result = await prisma.posts.findMany({
  where: {
    body: {
      search: 'France | United States',
    },
  },
})

The error message I receive is:
Invalid `prisma.job.findMany()` invocation:

Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(PostgresError { code: "42601", message: "syntax error in tsquery: \"Europe | United States\"", severity: "ERROR", detail: None, column: None, hint: None }), transient: false })

I think the error occurs because the search requires a single word, and "United States" is two words. Maybe PostgreSQL's tsquery does not handle multi-word phrases separated by spaces well in this context.

My team has run into the same issue before. We use pg-tsquery to ensure that incoming queries always conform to the underlying syntax necessary for search to work in Prisma queries.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-tsquery
import { Tsquery } from "pg-tsquery";

// Later...
const tsQueryParser = new Tsquery();
const fixedQuery = tsQueryParser.parseAndStringify(query);

const result = await prisma.posts.findMany({
  where: {
    body: {
      search: fixedQuery,
    },
  },
})

